# Unity3d 4.3.1f + Facebook SDK 4.3.6 doesnt build

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am trying everything I can for the last 3 days and I didnt find a way to make this version of their SDK work with the latest unity version (4.3.1).

FB SDK version 4.2.4 works fine on every Unity version I tried, but, 4.3.6 doesnt work with any of them (4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3).

Always gives me that weird message about java building:

> Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:Program
>   Files (x86)Javajre7binjavac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath
>   "E:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platforms/android-14android.jar" -d
>   "E:Unity Projects[project name]TempStagingAreabinclasses" -source 1.6
>   -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "comfacebookandroidR.java" "comwinterbigbangR.java"', CurrentDirectory='E:Unity Projects[project
>   name]TempStagingAreagen

Another weird thing, I setup my app to android 2.3.3 (API-10) why the hell it is trying to use android14?

With the combination of Unity 4.3.1 and FB SDK 4.2.4, I finally made it work flawless, but, I think that Ill be missing some good stuff from 4.3.6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a week long I think I found the problem.

I uninstalled all Java from my computer and installed Java 6 32bits. Now everything works as intended.